# Is it possible to add an engine to the tidymodels framework that is not currently included

Tags: r, tidymodels

I've been going through a lot of the [[tidymodels tutorials on rstudio][1](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/models/)](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/models/) and [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tidymodels%20) and I really like what I'm seeing. Questions:

1. Is it possible to add a modeling engine that is not currently
   included?
2. Is this a matter of including specific hooks in the engine or is the work performed on the tidymodels side?
3. Does documentation already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a new model and/or new models engine to the tidymodels framework! This involves functions from parsnip such as:

```
set_new_model()
set_model_mode()
set_model_engine()
set_dependency()
```

and more.

The best resource for how to set up a new model within the tidymodels framework is [this article on `tidymodels.org`](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/).